# How to run methods in UI thread from another non-UI thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winapi, win32gui

(Although this program is made by C# programming language, but the idea is from Win32. Let me elaborate on this.)

I create a message-only window in the Main thread (UI thread). After creating the window, I also start a new thread that posts windows messages to the main thread using `PostMessage` ([How to push some messages to a message queue in the main thread from another thread?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/869797/how-to-push-some-messages-to-a-message-queue-in-th.html)). In the `WndProc` of the message-only window, it response to some messages. For example, the `WM_CREATE_BROWSER` message will create a browser window using cef. In the process of creating the browser window, some handler (callback) can be used to response some events. For example, the `OnAfterCreated(CefBrowser browser)` method in `CefLifeSpanHandler` will be called once a new browser is created. that method (`OnAfterCreated`) runs in a different thread (not the main thread).  But my problem is precisely here.

In the `OnAfterCreated`, I got a underlying browser window (created by the c++ cef library), I want to save that browser (type CefBrowser) and do same addtional actions(e.g., get and save the handle of the browser window). But all of these actions should be executed in the main thread (UI thread), I don't how to execute these actions in the main thread from the non-UI thread. That seems to say althought some beginning statements are executed in the non-UI thread, but it have to switch to the main thread to execute the rest statements of `OnAfterCreated`. Let's see the code:

**Although the code is a bit long, it doesn't need to be read at all.**

- `_browserWindow = new BrowserWindow();` is creating a browser window in the UI thread.
- `protected override void OnAfterCreated(CefBrowser browser)` is responding the event in the process of creating the browser window. *But run in a non-UI thread*.
- `_core.OnBrowserAfterCreated(browser);` should run in the UI thread. My problem is there, how to run that code in the UI thread? (**Now, The only solution in my head is also to post messages to the UI thread.**)

```
private static IntPtr _hwndMsgOnly = IntPtr.Zero;
private const uint WM_CREATE_BROWSER = Win32.WM_USER;
private static BrowserWindow _browserWindow;

static void Main(string[] args) {
  IntPtr hInstance = Win32.GetModuleHandle(null);

  // Create window class
  // Register window class
  // Create window
  IntPtr hwnd = Win32.CreateWindowEx(
    0, classAtom, IntPtr.Zero, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    new IntPtr(Win32.HWND_MESSAGE), 
    IntPtr.Zero, hInstance, IntPtr.Zero);

  if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero) {
    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(), "Create the window failed");
  }

  _hwndMsgOnly = hwnd;

  Thread msgReceiver = new Thread(ReceiveMessages);
  msgReceiver.Start();

  Win32.MSG msg = new Win32.MSG();
  while (Win32.GetMessage(out msg, hwnd, 0, 0) != 0) {
    Win32.TranslateMessage(ref msg);
    Win32.DispatchMessage(ref msg);
  }
}

static void ReceiveMessages() {
  // 1. Receive messages from another process
  // 2. Post messages to the main thread
  if (_hwndMsgOnly != IntPtr.Zero) {
    Win32.PostMessage(_hwndMsgOnly, WM_CREATE_BROWSER, UIntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    // Win32.PostMessage(_hwndMsgOnly, Win32.WM_DESTROY, UIntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
  }
}

static IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 msg, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) {
  switch (msg) {
  case WM_CREATE_BROWSER:
    Console.WriteLine("msg: create browser");
    BrowserRuntime.InitializeCef();
    _browserWindow = new BrowserWindow();
    return IntPtr.Zero;

  case Win32.WM_DESTROY:
    Win32.PostQuitMessage(0);
    return IntPtr.Zero;
  }

  return Win32.DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

// =========================================
// BrowserWindow
// ========================================= 
class BrowserWindow {
  // Create browser window here
  // this is in the main thread
  public BrowserWindow() {
    BrowserClient client = new BrowserClient(this);
    CefWindowInfo windowInfo = CefWindowInfo.Create();
    CefBrowserSettings settings = new CefBrowserSettings{};

    // When creating the browser window, some events arise, but these event handler run in non-UI thread.
    CefBrowserHost.CreateBrowser(windowInfo, client, settings, StartUrl);
  }
  
  // Need to be called in the UI thread.
  internal protected virtual void OnBrowserAfterCreated(CefBrowser browser) {
    _browser = browser;
    _browserWindowHandle = _browser.GetHost().GetWindowHandle();
  }
}

// ===================================
// BrowserClient
// ===================================
internal class BrowserClient : CefClient {
  private readonly BrowserWindow _core;
  private readonly BrowserLifeSpanHandler _lifeSpanHandler;

  public BrowserClient(BrowserWindow core) {
    _core = core;
    _lifeSpanHandler = new BrowserLifeSpanHandler(core);
  }

  protected override CefLifeSpanHandler GetLifeSpanHandler() {
    return _lifeSpanHandler;
  }
}

// =========================================
// LiefSpanHandler
// =========================================
internal class BrowserLifeSpanHandler : CefLifeSpanHandler {
  private readonly BrowserWindow _core;

  public BrowserLifeSpanHandler(BrowserWindow core) {
    _core = core;
  }

  // This method run in non-UI thread
  protected override void OnAfterCreated(CefBrowser browser) {
    try {
      int tid = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
      base.OnAfterCreated(browser); 

      // But except posting messages to the UI thread, how can I call the following statements
      // in the UI thread. I don't use Windows Form.
      _core.OnBrowserAfterCreated(browser);

      // Windows Form way
      // _core.InvokeIfRequired(() => _core.OnBrowserAfterCreated(browser));
    } catch {
    }
  }
}
```

---

Maybe what I need is to implement my own version `BeginInvoke` and `Invoke`.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `Invoke` method (might be called `Dispatch` in WPF) that almost all UI controls in .NET have - you give it a delegate and it will run that delegate on the thread the control was created on. Maybe I've missed something in your requirements that means this won't work for you, but thought I would mention it

Comment: The solution is different for Win32 applications, which is different from WinForms, which is different from WPF, which is different from Windows' native XAML controls, which is different from WinUI 2, which is different from WinUI 3. You'll have to restrict the question to a single GUI framework.

Comment: @Dave I know that method, but now I dont use WPF or Windows Form control. so I dont have that convenience.

Comment: @IInspectable I want the Win32 way. I dont use any ui framework except the win32 api.

Comment: Obviously, those various frameworks have to ultimately *implement this functionality atop Win32*. If only you could [freely read the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,7765)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever this is really helpful. I thought it should be some `PostMessage` for the implementation `BeginInvoke` and `Invoke`, but i dont know the details. Now I can implement a simple version for solving my problem.

Comment: The simplest way would be to post or send a message to a window, and have the respective message handler run the code. That code always runs on the UI thread owning that window. Another option would be to exercise some of the lesser known COM infrastructure (see [Using contexts to return to a COM apartment later](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20191129-00/?p=103162)).

Comment: @IInspectable the COM way is fresh to me. As you saide, a solution based on 
`PostMessage` and Concurrent Queue is feasible. I also plan to implement that COM method.